# By 2010 means before 2010

Tags: prepositions

Does by 2010 for example means before 2010? I read a post here that by Tuesday means before Tuesday. I would like to know are they the same?

Best,

Comment: It can mean "before 2010 is out", that is, "before 2011".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*By [TIMEPOINT]* means "no later than [TIMEPOINT]". When [TIMEPOINT] is expressed as a *period* of time it is ambiguous whether *by* points to the beginning of the period or its end. If that is not explicitly stated you have to infer the meaning from context.

So  *by Tuesday* does not necessarily mean "before Tuesday"; if I say "You have to finish this report by Tuesday" I **probably** mean that it has to be submitted sometime during the workday on Tuesday. And *by 2010* does not necessarily mean "before 2010"; but if I say "By 2010 John was ready to move on to another job" I **probably** mean that John was dissatisfied with his current job in 2009 and started looking for another fairly early in 2010.

But neither of those inferences is certain. If it makes a difference in your situation, ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt and detailed reply. The sentence is this: "In 2001, English was the predominant language spoken at home by most people in the Cape Peninsula; however, by 2011 it had become less common, .. "

Comment: @shapol46 Note that perfect in the second clause: the present perfect is a present tense, and the clause means "In 2011 English was less common". There's no indication of *when* in 2011 the measure is taken, but over a ten-year period it doesn't really matter: the point is the change.